# I am not sure why I need to Encode path parameter TWICE to make the rest call with special chars to work?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, character-encoding

I have a rest call that Get's a product's ingredients and I use the product name as the path variable. I do allow any character used and I understand I need to do encodeURIComponent(name) to encode chars like "/" since they could be misinterpreted otherwise:

```
ProductController.js

loadProduct = function() {
....
this.productService.getProduct(encodeURIComponent(this.selectedProduct)).then{ ....}
}

productService.js

getProduct: function(productName) {
   let fullPath = "products/" + encodeURIComponent(productName);
   $http.get(fullPath) ....
}
```

I did some debugging on firefox and I noticed this:
Scenario 1: using only 1 encodeURI at the "getProduct" function (original assumption):
GET /products/test%2F
%2F is /
status 400 bad request
The "file column" in the Network tab shows the path as "test/" without the encoding

Scenario 2: using only 2 encodeURI at the both locations:
GET /products/test%252F      it seems because of 2nd encoding, the %25 is eocoding the % from %2F
status OK - returned the correct product "test/"
The "file column" in the Network tab shows the path as "test%2F" with the encoding correct on /

I am really confused here. I am not decoding on the fly or anything so really confused why i need to encode it twice or maybe I am using something wrong?

Comment: So it seems if i do   let fullPath = encodeURI("products/" + encodeURIComponent(productName));  the call works as well... maybe this is something I need to do since encoding includes the special chars and need to encodeURI on top of it? Seems redundant still...

Comment: What are you using for the web server here, Apache? If so, then this might have to do with the [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) setting ...?

Comment: What is `$http.get`? If `$http.get("/products/test%2F")` leads to `/products/test/` in the network tab, does `$http.get` perform one round of decoding?

Comment: no, the $http.get doesnt do any encoding....
My current suspicion is that when I do encodeURIComponent, the result + the rest api path needs to be encoded so the chars can be accepted?

Comment: I did try to use org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true and it does help with "///" so I dont need URIEncoded again BUT this doesn't help with other chars like "\\" which gets me 400. 
Is there a "catch all" for catalina?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried without encoding. Because the http packages will automatically do that encoding part you don't need to encode it. Please try without encoding.

Comment: I have - for example, if the product is called Prod1/xyz\ , the rest call will literally assume the / and \ as path parameters and break